# Call out Phone App in iPhone & fill in a phone number ( no dial )

Tags: ios, iphone

I know I can call out Phone App in iPhone & dial a phone number by:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12345678"]];
```

However, is there any way to call out Phone App & fill in a phone number only (no need to dial the number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear so, according to the official docs at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Sorry.

If you're trying to predial (eg for a calling card) then you could get input from the user, prepend your number, then call the tel URL in one feel swoop.  Is that the sort of thing you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: No. I just want to find an alternative way to dial short code phone numbers, e.g. `*1234`. Apple won't allow calling `tel:*1234`

Comment: I think that's due to the star.

Comment: Yes. Numbers with `*` and `#` cannot be dialed through programming.